# Mozilla firefox crashing - Kali Linux VM

Tags: linux, firefox, virtualbox, kali-linux

I just installed Kali Linux in VirtualBox, and I managed to get access to the system. However, my Mozilla is crashing every time I try to open it, and therefore, I have no current browser. It says "failed to execute default web browser input/output error".

When I try to write "sudo apt-get install firefox", it tells me:

> Package firefox is not available, but is referred to by another package.
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
> is only available from another source

> E: Package 'firefox' has no installation candidate

I don't know what to do.
Also, when I try to start Firefox by the command prompt. It tells me:

> 2020-07-12 10:23:05: minidump.cc:1571: ERROR: MinidumpThread has a memory region problem, 0x7ffe3c328dce+0x0, RVA 0x0x1b8
> 2020-07-12 10:23:05: minidump_processor.cc:255: ERROR: No memory region for /home/kali/.mozilla/firefox/hqv3wpa1.default-esr/minidumps/7cff5bc8-3c2b-c3fe-95ad-58709f24e079.dmp:0/5 id 0x8f0
> 2020-07-12 10:23:05: stackwalker_amd64.cc:272: ERROR: Can't get caller frame without memory or stack

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Firefox for Kali is Version 68 (not the current one). I have Kali running here in  a VM.  Run sudo apt autoremove to remove unused packages.  Then run sudo apt-get update followed by sudo apt-get upgrade to see if that fixes Firefox.  I am using Firefox here without issue.

Comment: @John I ran sudo apt autoremove and it tells me that "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded." then I ran sudo apt-get update and it tells me the same thing. Firefox is still crashing :(

Comment: I am not sure. I am in Kali 2020.2 here with Firefox V68.x.  I will keep looking around. Did you install some other software perhaps?   Try uninstalling Firefox and restarting following Installlion, and then install it again.   https://installlion.com/kali/kali/main/f/firefox-esr/uninstall/index.html

Comment: @John thanks for the reply. I did uninstalled Firefox and now when I click on "web browser", Chrome appears for me. At least now I have a browser :)

Comment: I will post the answer and perhaps you could acknowledge it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox for Kali is Version 68 (not the current one). I have Kali running here in a VM using Version 68.x. Given what you have tried, use the link below to uninstall Firefox.

https://installlion.com/kali/kali/main/f/firefox-esr/uninstall/index.html

This should allow Firefox or an alternate browser to work.